# Does antifreeze color matter?

Tags: coolant, antifreeze

I have a 2013 Kia Rio with an antifreeze that I don't know the formulation or brand, only that it is light green coloured, and wanted to change it.

Do I need to buy a light green color too or can I go with another coolant that is another color? the manual only says it must be ethylene glycol based.

Either way I will empty the entire radiator and flush it before changing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to drain and flush the radiator, then the color doesn't matter. Just stay within the specs for what the manufacturer says.

As a side note, I prefer to use the premix, personally (50% antifreeze/50% water). It seems like it might be a bit more expensive than buying the straight antifreeze and mixing it yourself (which it is). The big bonus for using it is you don't have to worry about the mix. When you put it in, it's good from the start. If you don't want to spend the little bit of extra money, ensure you used deionized water to do the mix. This will help the cooling system not get plugged up down the road.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I think I will follow your recommendation :)

Comment: @Doma17 I fully agree with Paulster2's answer. I comment separately to reinforce his statement that you should "...stay within the specs for what the [car] manufacturer says." This is crucial, as coolants do differ, and sometimes the wrong coolant can damage the cooling system (usually by deposits of unwanted, clogging mineral compounds), and sometimes coolants do have different colors. If you stick with the manufacturer's recommendation, however, you'll be fine.